# Best way to find differences recursively in two value objects in python?

Tags: python

So class A has a collection of class B and class B has some properties.

```
class A(object):
    bs = []

class B(object):
    propertyA
    propertyB
```

I need to be able to traverse the collection from the root of the aggregate and find all differencies between to aggregates.

So for example, one instance of A can differ from another by having additional B instance and by not having some B instance. And I need to do this recusively for every B that is in common beetween them.

A and B are value objects, so their identity completely depends on their attributes.

Right now I have three classed to incapsulate differencies

- ElementExistsDifference
- ElementNotExistsDifference
- ElementPropertyDifference.

Which are defined as:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

__author__ = 'michael'


class Differ():
    def __init__(self, one_item, another_item, difference):
        self.another_item = another_item
        self.one_item = one_item
        self.difference = difference

    def __repr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        one_str = str(self.one_item)
        two_str = str(self.two_item)
        diff_str = str(self.difference)
        return "{} differ from {} by {}".format(one_str, two_str, diff_str)


class AbstractDifference(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def compensate(self, db_api):
        pass

class NoDifference(AbstractDifference):

    def compensate(self, db_api):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Nothing"

class ItemDifference(AbstractDifference):

    @abstractmethod
    def compensate(self, db_api):
        pass

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.item)

class ExistsDifference(SchemaItemDifference):
    def compensate(self, api):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        item = super()
        return "Existence of {}".format(item)


class NotExistsDifference(ItemDifference):
    def compensate(self, api):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        item = super()
        return "Abscence of {}".format(item)


class ItemPropertyDifference(AbstractDifference):
    def compensate(self, api):
        pass

    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.property)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have thought about this problem a bit, considering the classes you have created. I am going to describe my own thought process regarding this problem and then define similar classes. Hopefully this will help you complete your solution.

You have value objects which have attributes. Those attributes can be plain values or they can be value objects.

You need to compare two trees to determine the differences between the two trees. You have defined many classes which you hope to annotate the differences in structure. I think that this is a good approach, however I think that you only need two classes to represent the difference.

```
class Match(object):
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

    def add_comparison(self, attribute, comparison):
        """ This adds the Match or Difference class for the attribute """
        setattr(self, attribute, comparison)

class Difference(object):
    def __init__(self, one, two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two
```

These two classes represent two objects or values which either match or differ.

If two value objects are present for the same attribute in their parent then they are considered to match. If the value objects have completely different attributes then *they still match*, but the attributes differ. The match holds references to the actual values so you can print them as required.

If two values are present for the same attribute in their parent and their values are equal then they are considered to match. Since they are not value objects there is no further comparison done.

If an attribute is missing, or an attribute differs substantially (i.e. one is a value object and another is a plain value) then they are considered to differ.

With these classes and rules we can then define the actual matcher. I have strived to use clear method names, but I have not implemented all the methods that this code uses. You will have to complete them. Hopefully that will not be too hard!

```
def generate_match_tree(one, two):
    # The is_value_object function should be able to handle None
    if not is_value_object(one) and not is_value_object(two):
        # If you need to handle lists then you would do that here
        if one == two:
            return Match(one, two)
        else:
            return Difference(one, two)

    if not is_value_object(one) or not is_value_object(two):
        return Difference(one, two)

    # Here we know one and two are both value objects, so they match.
    # We must consider the attributes of them now...

    result = Match(one, two)
    for attribute in get_all_attributes(one) + get_all_attributes(two):
        a_one = getattr(one, attribute)
        a_two = getattr(two, attribute)
        result.add_comparison(attribute, generate_match_tree(a_one, a_two))

    return result
```

Let me know if you need any more help.